# Cant pinpoint where "cannot convert 'double' to 'std::string*' in assignment" also yyparse() and yylex() error

Tags: c++, bison, yacc, flex-lexer, lex

I'm trying to pinpoint these error messages, but even when I move code around the error shows up at the same line.

Also why am I still getting "calc.y: In function 'int yyparse()':" and "calc.l: In function 'int yylex()':" even though I have it in my calc.y.

Error Messages

```
flex calc.l
bison -d calc.y
g++ -o calc calc.tab.c lex.yy.c
calc.y: In function 'int yyparse()':
calc.y:35: error: cannot convert 'double' to 'std::string*' in assignment
calc.tab.c:1490: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
calc.tab.c:1633: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
calc.l: In function 'int yylex()':
calc.l:17: error: 'yyerror' was not declared in this scope
```

calc.l

```
%{
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include "calc.tab.h"


%}
%%
"print"                     {return print;}
"exit"                      {return exit_command;}
[0-9]+                      {yylval.num = atof(yytext); return number;}
[_[:alpha:]][_[:alnum:]]*   {yylval.index = new std::string(yytext); return identifier; }
[ \t]                       ;
[\n]                        {return(CR);}
[-()+*/;=]                  {return yytext[0];}
.                           {ECHO; yyerror ("unexpected character");}

%%
int yywrap (void) {return 1;}
```

calc.y

```
%{
void yyerror (char *s);
int yylex(void);
#include <stdio.h>     /* C declarations used in actions */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <map>

static std::map<std::string, double> vars;
%}

%union {double num; std::string *index;}         /* Yacc definitions */
%start line
%token print
%token CR
%token exit_command
%token <num> number
%token <index> identifier
%type <num> line exp term 
%type <index> assignment

%%

/* descriptions of expected inputs     corresponding actions */

line    : assignment CR         {;}
        | exit_command CR       {exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);}
        | print exp CR          {printf("Printing %f\n", $2);}
        | line assignment CR    {;}
        | line print exp CR     {printf("Printing %f\n", $3);}
        | line exit_command CR  {exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);}
        ;

assignment : identifier '=' exp  {$$ = vars[*$1] = $3; delete $1; }
            ;
exp     : term                  {$$ = $1;}
        | exp '+' term          {$$ = $1 + $3;}
        | exp '-' term          {$$ = $1 - $3;}
        | exp '*' term          {$$ = $1 * $3;}
        | exp '/' term          {$$ = $1 / $3;}
        | '(' exp ')'           {$$ = $2;}
        ;
term    : number                {$$ = $1;}
        | identifier            {$$ = vars[*$1]; delete $1; } 
        ;

%%                    

int main (void) {


    return yyparse();
}

extern int yyparse();

void yyerror (char *s)
 {
    extern int yylineno;  // defined and maintained in lex
    extern char *yytext;  // defined and maintained in lex
    fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one place where the `double` to `std::string*` error will be produced:

```
assignment : identifier '=' exp  {$$ = vars[*$1] = $3; delete $1; }
```

The type of `assignment` is `<index>`, which is `std::string*`. The type of `exp` is `<num>`, which is `double`. So in the action above, `$$` is a `std::string*`, and `$3` is a `double` (as is `vars[*$1]`).

My best guess is that you didn't intend the semantic type of `assignment` to be `<index>`.

As for the fact that `yyerror` isn't defined in `calc.l`, that is clearly true. `yyerror` is defined in `calc.y`, and the declaration is also in `calc.y`. The C programs produced by (f)lex and yacc/bison are different programs, and they are compiled independently, so the fact that `yyerror` is declared in the yacc/bison-generated program does not make it's declaration visible to the (f)lex-generated program. If you need to use it from a (f)lex action, you'll need to declare it in both files.

These warnings:

```
calc.tab.c:1490: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
```

suggest that you should find a newer version of `bison`. If that is impossible, you can just ignore them; `g++` is complaining that the bison template is not C++-clean, because it is assigning a string literal (which is a `const char*`) to a `char*` variable without a cast. Newer bison versions avoid the warning.

Comment: So do I move that case into exp and delete assignment all together?

When I do I get "calc.y: conflicts: 4 shift/reduce."

Comment: @Jo0b4k4: no, just change its type declaration. You have `%type <index> assignment` in your declarations section. To make assignment an expression would change your language; if you want to do it, you'll have to think through the operator precedence of assignment.

Comment: Awesome that just fixed everything! I totally deserve a slap in the face for something as simple as that.